# How do I tune random forest with oob error?

Tags: mlr3

Instead of doing a CV and train the Random Forest multiple times I would like to use the OOB Error as and unbiased estimation of the generalized error.

And for a few data points (in the low thousands), does it make sense to use the OOB error instead of CV, since it might be possible that only a few data points are oob?

So far I could only find something about it from this issue thread https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/338 from mlr. I think it is suggested to use a hould out split with almost only training data.

I found the insample resampling method https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_resamplings_insample.html which uses the same data for training and testing.

This is my code:

```
learner = as_learner(
  po("select", selector=selector_name(selection)) %>>% po("learner", learner=lrn("regr.ranger"))
)


sp = ps(
  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio = p_dbl(0, 1),
  regr.ranger.replace = p_fct(c(TRUE, FALSE)),
  regr.ranger.sample.fraction = p_dbl(0.1, 1),
  regr.ranger.num.trees = p_int(1, 2000)
)

at = auto_tuner(
  resampling = rsmp("insample"),
  method = "random_search",
  learner = learner,
  measure = msr("oob_error"),
  term_evals = 5,
  search_space=sp
)

learners = c(at)
resamplings = rsmp("cv", folds = 5)

design = benchmark_grid(task, learners, resamplings)
bmr = benchmark(design)
```

But when running the code above, I get the error: `Error in learner$oob_error() : attempt to apply non-function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the resulting `GraphLearner` does not have the method `oob_error()` anymore. This is similar to the issues here:

https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3pipelines/issues/291

Edit: Add workaround.

This suggestion should be seen as a **workaround**.

The idea is that it is possible to write custom measures as mentioned in the comments. A tutorial on that can be found in the [mlr3 book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/extending.html#extending-measures)

This custom measure only works in this specific case, because it is tailored to the specific structure of the `GraphLearner`. For a different learner, the measure would have to be adjusted.

```r
library(mlr3verse)
#> Loading required package: mlr3

task = tsk("mtcars")

selection = c("mpg", "cyl")

learner = as_learner(
  po("select", selector = selector_name(selection)) %>>% po("learner", learner = lrn("regr.ranger"))
)


sp = ps(
  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio = p_dbl(0, 1),
  regr.ranger.replace = p_fct(c(TRUE, FALSE)),
  regr.ranger.sample.fraction = p_dbl(0.1, 1),
  regr.ranger.num.trees = p_int(1, 2000)
)


MyMeasure = R6::R6Class(
  "MyMeasure",
  inherit = MeasureRegr,
  public = list(
    initialize = function() {
      super$initialize(
        id = "MyMeasure",
        range = c(-Inf, Inf),
        minimize = TRUE,
        predict_type = "response",
        properties = "requires_learner"
      )
    }
  ),
  private = list(
    .score = function(prediction, learner, ...) {
      model = learner$state$model$regr.ranger
      if (is.null(model)) stop("Set store_models = TRUE.")
      model$model$prediction.error
    }
  )
)



at = auto_tuner(
  resampling = rsmp("insample"),
  method = "random_search",
  learner = learner,
  measure = MyMeasure$new(),
  term_evals = 1,
  search_space = sp,
  store_models = TRUE
)

learners = c(at)
resamplings = rsmp("cv", folds = 5)

design = benchmark_grid(task, learners, resamplings)

lgr::get_logger("mlr3")$set_threshold(NULL)
lgr::get_logger("mlr3tuning")$set_threshold(NULL)


bmr = benchmark(design)
#> INFO  [23:28:45.638] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 5 resampling iterations
#> INFO  [23:28:45.740] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger.tuned' on task 'mtcars' (iter 1/5)
#> INFO  [23:28:47.112] [bbotk] Starting to optimize 4 parameter(s) with '<OptimizerRandomSearch>' and '<TerminatorEvals> [n_evals=1, k=0]'
#> INFO  [23:28:47.158] [bbotk] Evaluating 1 configuration(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:47.201] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 1 resampling iterations
#> INFO  [23:28:47.209] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger' on task 'mtcars' (iter 1/1)
#> INFO  [23:28:47.346] [mlr3] Finished benchmark
#> INFO  [23:28:47.419] [bbotk] Result of batch 1:
#> INFO  [23:28:47.424] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:47.424] [bbotk]               0.5708216                TRUE                   0.4830289
#> INFO  [23:28:47.424] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees MyMeasure warnings errors runtime_learners
#> INFO  [23:28:47.424] [bbotk]                   1209  11.39842        0      0            0.124
#> INFO  [23:28:47.424] [bbotk]                                 uhash
#> INFO  [23:28:47.424] [bbotk]  abfcaa2f-8b01-4821-8e8b-1d209fbe2229
#> INFO  [23:28:47.444] [bbotk] Finished optimizing after 1 evaluation(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:47.445] [bbotk] Result:
#> INFO  [23:28:47.447] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:47.447] [bbotk]               0.5708216                TRUE                   0.4830289
#> INFO  [23:28:47.447] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees learner_param_vals  x_domain MyMeasure
#> INFO  [23:28:47.447] [bbotk]                   1209          <list[6]> <list[4]>  11.39842
#> INFO  [23:28:47.616] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger.tuned' on task 'mtcars' (iter 2/5)
#> INFO  [23:28:47.733] [bbotk] Starting to optimize 4 parameter(s) with '<OptimizerRandomSearch>' and '<TerminatorEvals> [n_evals=1, k=0]'
#> INFO  [23:28:47.758] [bbotk] Evaluating 1 configuration(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:47.799] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 1 resampling iterations
#> INFO  [23:28:47.807] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger' on task 'mtcars' (iter 1/1)
#> INFO  [23:28:47.900] [mlr3] Finished benchmark
#> INFO  [23:28:47.969] [bbotk] Result of batch 1:
#> INFO  [23:28:47.971] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:47.971] [bbotk]               0.9683787               FALSE                   0.4303312
#> INFO  [23:28:47.971] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees MyMeasure warnings errors runtime_learners
#> INFO  [23:28:47.971] [bbotk]                    112  9.594568        0      0            0.084
#> INFO  [23:28:47.971] [bbotk]                                 uhash
#> INFO  [23:28:47.971] [bbotk]  4bb2742b-49e2-4b02-adc4-ffaa70aef8d4
#> INFO  [23:28:47.984] [bbotk] Finished optimizing after 1 evaluation(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:47.984] [bbotk] Result:
#> INFO  [23:28:47.986] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:47.986] [bbotk]               0.9683787               FALSE                   0.4303312
#> INFO  [23:28:47.986] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees learner_param_vals  x_domain MyMeasure
#> INFO  [23:28:47.986] [bbotk]                    112          <list[6]> <list[4]>  9.594568
#> INFO  [23:28:48.116] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger.tuned' on task 'mtcars' (iter 3/5)
#> INFO  [23:28:48.241] [bbotk] Starting to optimize 4 parameter(s) with '<OptimizerRandomSearch>' and '<TerminatorEvals> [n_evals=1, k=0]'
#> INFO  [23:28:48.266] [bbotk] Evaluating 1 configuration(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:48.308] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 1 resampling iterations
#> INFO  [23:28:48.316] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger' on task 'mtcars' (iter 1/1)
#> INFO  [23:28:48.413] [mlr3] Finished benchmark
#> INFO  [23:28:48.480] [bbotk] Result of batch 1:
#> INFO  [23:28:48.483] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:48.483] [bbotk]               0.4089994                TRUE                   0.1780138
#> INFO  [23:28:48.483] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees MyMeasure warnings errors runtime_learners
#> INFO  [23:28:48.483] [bbotk]                    620  38.86261        0      0            0.089
#> INFO  [23:28:48.483] [bbotk]                                 uhash
#> INFO  [23:28:48.483] [bbotk]  9b47bdb0-15dc-421d-9091-db2e6c41cbee
#> INFO  [23:28:48.495] [bbotk] Finished optimizing after 1 evaluation(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:48.496] [bbotk] Result:
#> INFO  [23:28:48.498] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:48.498] [bbotk]               0.4089994                TRUE                   0.1780138
#> INFO  [23:28:48.498] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees learner_param_vals  x_domain MyMeasure
#> INFO  [23:28:48.498] [bbotk]                    620          <list[6]> <list[4]>  38.86261
#> INFO  [23:28:48.646] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger.tuned' on task 'mtcars' (iter 4/5)
#> INFO  [23:28:48.763] [bbotk] Starting to optimize 4 parameter(s) with '<OptimizerRandomSearch>' and '<TerminatorEvals> [n_evals=1, k=0]'
#> INFO  [23:28:48.788] [bbotk] Evaluating 1 configuration(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:48.829] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 1 resampling iterations
#> INFO  [23:28:48.837] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger' on task 'mtcars' (iter 1/1)
#> INFO  [23:28:48.959] [mlr3] Finished benchmark
#> INFO  [23:28:49.027] [bbotk] Result of batch 1:
#> INFO  [23:28:49.030] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:49.030] [bbotk]               0.3449179               FALSE                    0.344375
#> INFO  [23:28:49.030] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees MyMeasure warnings errors runtime_learners
#> INFO  [23:28:49.030] [bbotk]                   1004  11.96155        0      0            0.112
#> INFO  [23:28:49.030] [bbotk]                                 uhash
#> INFO  [23:28:49.030] [bbotk]  d14754c3-ab73-4777-84bd-10daa10318f0
#> INFO  [23:28:49.043] [bbotk] Finished optimizing after 1 evaluation(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:49.044] [bbotk] Result:
#> INFO  [23:28:49.046] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:49.046] [bbotk]               0.3449179               FALSE                    0.344375
#> INFO  [23:28:49.046] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees learner_param_vals  x_domain MyMeasure
#> INFO  [23:28:49.046] [bbotk]                   1004          <list[6]> <list[4]>  11.96155
#> INFO  [23:28:49.203] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger.tuned' on task 'mtcars' (iter 5/5)
#> INFO  [23:28:49.327] [bbotk] Starting to optimize 4 parameter(s) with '<OptimizerRandomSearch>' and '<TerminatorEvals> [n_evals=1, k=0]'
#> INFO  [23:28:49.352] [bbotk] Evaluating 1 configuration(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:49.393] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 1 resampling iterations
#> INFO  [23:28:49.401] [mlr3] Applying learner 'select.regr.ranger' on task 'mtcars' (iter 1/1)
#> INFO  [23:28:49.537] [mlr3] Finished benchmark
#> INFO  [23:28:49.614] [bbotk] Result of batch 1:
#> INFO  [23:28:49.616] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:49.616] [bbotk]               0.4485645               FALSE                   0.4184389
#> INFO  [23:28:49.616] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees MyMeasure warnings errors runtime_learners
#> INFO  [23:28:49.616] [bbotk]                   1931  12.59067        0      0            0.127
#> INFO  [23:28:49.616] [bbotk]                                 uhash
#> INFO  [23:28:49.616] [bbotk]  295d1dc0-810d-4351-9bb4-7255fca38be3
#> INFO  [23:28:49.629] [bbotk] Finished optimizing after 1 evaluation(s)
#> INFO  [23:28:49.630] [bbotk] Result:
#> INFO  [23:28:49.631] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.mtry.ratio regr.ranger.replace regr.ranger.sample.fraction
#> INFO  [23:28:49.631] [bbotk]               0.4485645               FALSE                   0.4184389
#> INFO  [23:28:49.631] [bbotk]  regr.ranger.num.trees learner_param_vals  x_domain MyMeasure
#> INFO  [23:28:49.631] [bbotk]                   1931          <list[6]> <list[4]>  12.59067
#> INFO  [23:28:49.806] [mlr3] Finished benchmark
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: oh thank you. After I replaced the pipeline with a normal learner and added `store_models=TRUE` to the auto tuner, it worked. I guess there is currently no work around? And using `insample` resampling is the correct way?

Comment: A workaround would be write a custom measure (https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/extending.html#extending-measures). In that custom measure you would have to call something like `learner$graph$pipeops$<learner-id>$oob_error()` in the score method.

Comment: And yes, the insampel resampling is the correct way. Note that I have extended the answer to include the workaround :) I hope this solves your problems!